# UITextField strange behaviour on resignFirstResponder

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield

Already the second day and cannot figure out the problem,

I've `UITabelView` with Custom `UICellViews`, each custom `UICellView` consists of `UILabel` and `UITextField`.

Custom `UICellView` object allocs `UITextField` and `UILabel` in its `init` method and are released in `dealloc`.

The number of custom `UICellViews` in `UITableView` is 6.

The user scenario is following

- When user clicks from from 1 to 5 `UITextFields` virtual keyboard opens and user types some text
- When user clicks on the 6th `UITextField` if virtual keyboard is active, it should be hidden, and if it is hidden it shall not be displayed.

As implement `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol in my `UIViewController` class and set the delegate of each `UITextField` to self.

My delegate methods are following

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag != 6) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
}

-(BOOL)  textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
     /* Some code */
}

-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

All the functions are properly !

So now, the virtual keyboard is never get hidden, why this happens ?

PS. Similar code has worked on iPhone but this issue exists on iPad.

Comment: Check with your tag allocation to UITextFields. Have you set tag in range of 0-5 or 1-6?

Comment: Tag is correct, corresponding if's else branches is called i.e. resignFirstResponder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to know which textfield was last used! so you can do `[lastUsedTextField resignFirstResponder]`

There is a dirty, but working trick.. you can make your textfield the new active UITextField and call resignFirstResponder in the next cycle immediately:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag != 6) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        // this will schedule keyboard dismissal for the current text field
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
        });
        return YES; // -> make this one active
    }
}
```

Comment: Ow thanks man !!! many many !! But I still don't get why the keyboard was not getting hidden in textFieldShouldEndEditing ? Any ideas ?

Comment: maybe because the focus moved from one field to another? in that case, the keyboard is still up, but your text field is not the first responder anymore so resignFirstResponder will do nothing

Comment: OK, still its strange as on iPhone the same code has worked ... however thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

did you seted action for textField?

```
[YourTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDoneEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

PS set any selector for any ControlEvent

Comment: No, why should I do it ? Aren't the delegate methods for that purpose ?

Comment: Did you tested them? Are you shure thay are called?

Comment: Yes, They are all called appropriately